# How to check an input if the another input is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to auto check a hidden array of checkboxes if another checkbox is checked

My HTML code (I'm using laravel .blade views) :

```
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="check[]" value="{{ $booking->teacher_rate * $booking->duration }}">
</td>
<td>{{ $booking->id }}</td>
<input id="booking_id[]" name="booking_id[]" class="hidden" type="checkbox" style="visibility: hidden" value="{{ $booking->id }}">
```

Heres my code:

```
$.each($("input[name='check[]']:checked"), function( index, value){
    var i = index;            
    $('input[name="booking_id[]"]').map(function(index){ 
        var $this = $(this);
        if(i == index) { $this.prop('checked', true); } 
    }).get();  
});
```

It's not working out for me when I'm trying to get their values.

```
var ids = $('input[name="booking_id[]:checked"]').map(function(){ 
    return this.value; 
}).get();  

console.log(ids);
```

Comment: Please show a reduced HTML example along with your JS, like boil it down to 3 or 4 lines of HTML.

Comment: Why is `:checked` inside the `name` attribute selector? You’ve already used the correct selector here: `$("input[name='check[]']:checked")`.

Comment: Well for one, your HTML alone deformed, having an input randomly inside a ```<tr>``` tag is incorrect markup. If the markup is malformed, then this alone can cause an array of issues for your JavaScript when trying to navigate the DOM.

Comment: @ Xufox Thanks dude... this was the reason!
I feel dumb as hell...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect, the :checked should come out of the selector.

I've provided an alternative method of solving your issue, which uses slightly different code. I've attached a click event to each of your input checkboxes that are visible, the following line of code then checks/unchecks the hidden one as per the visible one:

```
$(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='booking_id[]']").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
```

- `$(this)` start with the clicked checkbox
- `.closest("tr")` move up the DOM tree until we find the first row element
- `.find("input[name='booking_id[]']")` search back down the DOM tree for any input with a name 'booking_id[]'
- `.prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'))` change the property `checked` of the current element (i.e. the booking_id checkbox), to match the `checked` property of the element originally clicked

---

## Demo

```js
// Add click event to each of your visible checkboxes
$(document).on("click", "input[name='check[]']", function() {

  // Traverse up DOM to row, then find any input with booking_id[] name, mark this as checked/unchecked as per visible one
  $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='booking_id[]']").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));

});



$("#compile").click( function() {
var ids = $('input[name="booking_id[]"]:checked').map(function() {
  return this.value;
}).get();
console.log(ids);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>


  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="check[]" value="10"></td>
    <td>ID10</td>
    <td>
    <input id="booking_id[]" name="booking_id[]" class="hidden" type="checkbox" style="visibility: hidden" value="ID10">
</td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="check[]" value="20"></td>
    <td>ID20</td>
    <td>
    <input id="booking_id[]" name="booking_id[]" class="hidden" type="checkbox" style="visibility: hidden" value="ID20">
</td>
  </tr>
  
  

  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="check[]" value="30"></td>
    <td>ID30</td>
    <td>
    <input id="booking_id[]" name="booking_id[]" class="hidden" type="checkbox" value="ID30">Unhidden for demo purposes
</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>

<button id="compile"> Compile</button>
```

Comment: This is the best comment ever!
Thanks for clearing it up too